# Where the column sequence_value refer in sequence_product table in Magneto 2

Tags: magento2

During debugging an issue I found that table "catalog_product_index_tier_price" has a column entity_id which refers to table "sequence_product" column sequence_value. Now for further tracking this sequence_value their is no reference defined for this?

Where actually this sequence_value column values referenced for?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Found myself with the same question today.

Debugging further I found that `sequence_product.sequence_value` has a relation with `catalog_product_entity.entity_id` and `cataloginventory_stock_item.product_id`.

That gives me the impression `sequence_product` is used to maintain a legacy relation for tables that are not in the content staging schema, given that now the primary key for `catalog_product_entity` is `row_id`.